# Unpack value into multiple variable in python

Tags: python, unpack

Below code works. However I cannot re-create it/not understand it. Could someone pls help to write all lines to complete the code.

```
value = #something
var1, var2 =  unpack("b8s",value)
```

That means, here one value is being put into two variables. Can someone give an example, how its possible?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know what a tuple is?

Comment: yes, but i just modified the problem, its more like unpacking to multivariable issue, no relation with tuple now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unpack` method is coming from the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module, which is lets you treat a Python string like packed binary data. The `unpack('b8s', value)` call is telling `unpack` to treat `value` like a binary string containing one unsigned char (`using 'b'`), which will be unpacked as the integer value of the char, followed by a `char[8]` (using `'8s'`), meaning a `char` string of length 8. That gets unpacked as a Python string. So a full example would look like this:

```
>>> from struct import unpack
>>> s = "abcdefgty"
>>> int_char, my_str = unpack("b8s", s)
>>> print int_char
97  # 97 is the ascii code of 'a'
>>> print my_str
bcdefgty
```

Comment: Got it finally, thanks dano. in 'b8s' i'am dividing the value into two parts, hence the two variables. Had i write 'bc7s' i could put them into three variables, like var1, var2, var3  =  unpack("bc7s",value).  So, number of variables come from in how many format i am dividing the value.

Answer (score 5):

You're over complicating it by having a loop at all.

```
var1, var2 = tuple
```

This is just a syntax thing you can do in python. Note that you must unpack the *entire tuple*; the number of variables on the left-hand side must be equal to the number of values in the tuple.

---

Example

```
myTuple = ("hi","i","am","tuple")
first,second,third,fourth = myTuple
print first
>>hi
print second
>>i
print third
>>am
print fourth
>>tuple
```

---

Not allowed

```
myTuple = ("hi","i","am","tuple")
first,second = myTuple
>>Exception
```

Comment: Can you give a complete code as an example pls? Thanks

Comment: Note that in Python3, you can actually do partial unpacking, like this: `first, second, *_ = myTuple`. In that case, `_` will end up containing the tuple `("am", "tuple")`.

Comment: This way works, but need to use this line as it is in coding:  var1, var2 =  unpack("b8s",value)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a tuple as

```
t = (1, 2, "a")
```

you can unpack it like this:

```
a, b, c = t
print "a=", a
```

which prints

> a= 1

Comment: I know this type unpack works, however I was wondering if its possible to give an example by keeping this line intact :  var1, var2 =  unpack("b8s",value)

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is: `unpack` process the contents of `elem` and returning a tuple with 2 items. Each item is assigned to a different variable.

it's the same:

```
unpacked_value =  unpack("b8s",elem)
var1 = unpacked_value[0]
var2 = unpacked_value[1]
```

Using diffentd values and variables:

```
my_tuple = (1, 2)
var1, var2 = my_tuple
print var1 #outputs 1
print var2 #outputs 2
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you keep this line intact and add other required codings up and down pls?  var1, var2 =  unpack("b8s",value)